How can I return a value from a column after an Insert or Update in Advantage StreamlineSQL ODBC
In Postgres it would be done this easily:
INSERT 
  INTO Table (value, value1, value2)
VALUES 
  ('value', 'value1', 'value2') 
RETURNING last_id;

Or can you create a function that inserts and returns that data at the same time?
Any help is appreciated,
Greetings!

Use LASTROWID() to get the new ID value
INSERT INTO table(name) VALUES('foo');

SELECT LASTROWID() FROM table;

